# How to imitate cd command in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, cd

Giving you two path, one is for the original path, and another is the parameter of the `cd` command.

For Example:

`users/documents` and `stackOverFlow` should return `users/documents/stackOverFlow`

and

`users/documents` and `../stackOverFlow` should return `users/stackOverFlow`

and

`users/documents/test` and `../../stackOverFlow` should return `users/stackOverFlow`

How can we implement such a method 
`imitateCDCommand` with two parameters `str1` and `str2` and return the destination path.

Comment: Use the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API

Comment: Please tell / show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
// ...
public static String imitateCDCommand(dir1, dir2) throws IOException {
  File file1 = new File(dir1);
  File file2 = new File(file1, dir2);
  return file2.getCanonicalPath();
}
```